# Nativescript-vue. Using SVG Graphics, Images, Icons

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to know if it is posible to use images and icons in svg format and how to use it.

I am using nativescript-vue 6.0 with typescript.

Comment: searched, found https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4649 which points to https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-svg

Comment: SVG is not supported out of the box. You will need a plugin, you can always find all available plugins at https://market.nativescript.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way to display vector graphics is an icon font. I use the plugin [nativescript-fonticon](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon) and generate the font with [Fontello](http://fontello.com/), which lets you upload custom icons and set the unicode value.

Some tips:

- You have to format your icon css classes like this: `.your-icon-name:before { content: "\f80b"; }` or the plugin won't recognize it
- You might have to edit the vector files [as explained](https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-use-custom-images#importing-svg-images) and set the same height
- On Android, your icons will scale with the device font size